# Uninitialized class fields and STL containers

Tags: c++

Does STL default allocator zero raw memory before placing objects into it? See this code. The comments reflect the behavior on my platform.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() {} // n isn't initialized 
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> v(2); // zeroed
    std::cout << v[0].n << '\n';
    std::cout << v[1].n << '\n';

    Foo foo; // contains garbage
    std::cout << foo.n << '\n';
}
```

Is it possible to disable zeroing raw memory? Note, it isn't the same as value initializing POD.

Comment: Can you describe why you want it to be disabled? Efficiency issue or other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A container will default-initialize the objects it creates if you don't give them a specific value. In your case the default constructor for the object does *not* initialize the POD integer, so it will contain whatever was left over in memory.

Sometimes new heap blocks will be zero initialized by the OS, but you can't even count on that. A block can get reused and again it will contain leftover garbage from the last time it was used.

Code that is ultra sensitive to exploits will take care to zero out memory to critical variables such as passwords before destroying them.

Answer (score 4):

It might zero memory. It might not. It might get it back from your favourite operating system already zeroed- I know that Windows has a habit of zeroing memory. One thing is for sure- it's not defined and you won't find any control settings for it in the Standard API.

Comment: this. Just initialize n in the initializer list, that's what it is for

Comment: @stijn: No, he wants to *disable* it, not *enable* it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your free store is being zero-filled, but not your call stack. C++ certainly isn't doing any zero-initialisation here, and this has nothing to do with containers.

I reckon you'll see the same if you try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() {} // n isn't initialized 
    int n;
};

int main()
{
   Foo foo; // arbitrary values
   std::cout << foo.n << '\n';

   Foo* p = new Foo; // zero values
   std::cout << p->n << '\n';
   delete p;
}
```

(Unfortunately, ideone.com doesn't exhibit the behaviour for the automatic-storage variable which is a shame. Probably something to do with the locked-down environment in which `g++` is invoked for snippets. Still, [I get to show off my cunning use of `#pragma`](http://www.ideone.com/TYjyw)!)

---

There's no C++ way to control this, and there's no Windows or Linux way to control it as far as I know.

Incidentally, whatever has led you to this requirement is a good example of why you shouldn't rely on non-initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Vector initializes its elements with copies of a default-initialized object, so in your case you get copies of an arbitrary value. There is no way to disable this behaviour.